# Is there a formula that I can use so that I can get a cell on Sheet 1 to have exactly the same formatting as a cell on Sheet 2?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, colors, conditional-formatting

I am using an excel spreadsheet to record skill competencies of staff.  Sheet 1 will act as a "master" sheet reflecting the skill competencies of all staff (ie different employee in each column) and sheets 1,2,3,4 etc will be used for smaller groups of staff (departments).

I am using Red - no competency, Orange - limited competency, Green - competent as colour codes next to each skill, to indicate where each staff member is at.

If I change the colour on one of the department spreadsheets (for example, sheet 2), how can I get it to automatically update the colour on the master spreadsheet (sheet 1)

Help!  THanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the indicator, you might try Ctrl+C the source cell, then on the Master Sheet Shift+Edit+PastePictureLink.
If your master sheet is just a summary of your other sheets this should work.

If you need to do cumulative totals of competencies, such as red and green, numeric ranges might serve you, and then you could do conditional formatting.

Not clear what you mean by "colour on one of the department spreadsheets" and so maybe you are totaling the competencies in some fashion.